# How to automatically click a button on a website on daily basis

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-services, browser, service-worker

I aim to click a specific button on a specific website daily (Ex: at 12:00 PM).

This should be fully automatic, I mean, my computer may be on/off.

Could you please suggest a solution, idea of how to do so?

Note: I want to use JS.

Thanks.

Comment: is it a static website or dynamic one where you need to login or authenticate to see the button?

Comment: It is dynamic, I have to log in first.  
@Srikanth

Comment: What is the purpose behind this?

Comment: Check-in and check-out automatically. @JavaScript

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. please take a moment and read this article [ask] about how to ask questions also read this article [mre] about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement. Good luck 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a name for that - Crawler.
You can use the Puppeteer library to create a headless web browser and simulate any kind of action.

The production may be on a public server, like Heroku or Deta.

[Puppeteer dev web documentation](https://pptr.dev/)

Comment: Got it fixed @JavaScript

Comment: @AvivBenShahar, Does this require a lot of work and effort?

Comment: @Ahmad - NOPE. I actually use it a lot. Consider using typescript for better code completion. All the documentation is on the web, and the API is pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

TestCafe (https://testcafe.io) is my tool of choice for this purpose.  Once setup, the schedule can be automated with something like [node-cron](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nodejs-cron-jobs-by-examples)

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
I will check it out and let you know if any further help/question is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **setInterval**

```
setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 8.64e+7);
```

this function will execute after every 24 hours.

Comment: My PC may be off, so this solution won't work.